# How to Install react-native-video-processing in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video, video-processing

**android/app/build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
// The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")

// video processing 

implementation project(':react-native-video-processing')

// phone number otp

implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.2.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.8.3'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet:16.0.0-beta04'

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
    implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
```

}

**setting.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'LoginGoogle'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-        
android/native_modules.gradle")
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')

// Include react-native-video-processing module
include ':react-native-video-processing'
project(':react-native-video-processing').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,'../node_modules/react-native-video-processing/android')
```

**mainApplication.java**

```
// video processing 

import com.shahenlibrary.RNVideoProcessingPackage;
```

**error:**

```
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/yqritc/android- 
     scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/yqritc/android- 
     scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
       - file:/D:/Code/ReactNative/BrandingProfitable/LoginGoogle/node_modules/jsc- 
     android/dist/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/yqritc/android- 
     scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android- 
     scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
         Required by:
             project :app > project :react-native-video-processing`
```

***So I am gettng the error in this Configuration, so How can i install 'react-native-video-processing' dependecy?***

**android/app/build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
// The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")

// video processing 

implementation project(':react-native-video-processing')

// phone number otp

implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.2.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.8.3'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet:16.0.0-beta04'

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
    implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
```

}

**setting.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'LoginGoogle'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-        
android/native_modules.gradle")
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')

// Include react-native-video-processing module
include ':react-native-video-processing'
project(':react-native-video-processing').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,'../node_modules/react-native-video-processing/android')
```

**mainApplication.java**

```
// video processing 

import com.shahenlibrary.RNVideoProcessingPackage;
```

**error:**

```
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/yqritc/android- 
     scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/yqritc/android- 
     scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
       - file:/D:/Code/ReactNative/BrandingProfitable/LoginGoogle/node_modules/jsc- 
     android/dist/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/yqritc/android- 
     scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android- 
     scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
         Required by:
             project :app > project :react-native-video-processing`
```

***So I am gettng the error in this Configuration, so How can i install 'react-native-video-processing' dependecy?***